# T-SQL reset sequence every x records for group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking to create a dataset to categorise customers into specific groups for each customer type - I want to apply a numbering system to start at 1 for each customer type and group every 3 records for the customer type

In the sample below, I can see that the **AUTO** Customer type has 4 groups (3 x 3 & 1 x 2), **BUIL** has 1 group of 3, **MANU** has 3 groups (2 x 3 & 1 x 1) etc.

[image: Sample]

I was originally looking at the NTILE, but my groups have differing row counts per customer type so cannot dynamically alter the NTILE value AFAIK.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

wildshark-uk

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Data as text, with DDL, makes it much easier to help you. It's hard to test a query on a picture of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a column that specifies the ordering, you can just use `row_number()` and arithmetic:

```
select t.*,
       ceiling(row_number() over (partition by customer_type order by <ordering col>) / 3.0)
from t;
```

If you do not care about the ordering but just the grouping into triads, you can use `order by (select null)`.

And finally, SQL Server supports updatable CTEs and subqueries, so you can use this query in an `update` as well.

Comment: You are an absolute star - it didn't even cross my mind to apply the ceiling function - That's solved my problem - thank you so much :)